# Controller responds with 415 response for any MIME type other than application/json

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I wrote a spring boot application. I have a question on how spring treats requests to controller end points. I have an endpoint with only "path" attribute specified and no produces, consumes attribute specified. When I hit the end point with "application/json" content-type, I get back the response. But when I hit the end point with other content-types like "application/xml, text etc", I get back 415. I couldn't understand how produces and consumes are treated.

Comment: issue resolved?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Spring 4, which by default returns error response in json format rather than the requested format. This issue seems to be fixed in Spring 5.

Answer (score 1):

`Consumes` means the client has to provide `application/json` when putting/posting, `Produces` on the other hand means, that the client will get an `application/json` as result.

You can add as many MediaTypes as you like, but at some point you need to provide multiple endpoints for the same result but in different MediaTypes.

So in your case you would need to annotate your contoller method with

```
@GetMapping(value = "/path", produces = {"application/json", "application/vnd.custom+json"})
```

As far as I know, spring just defaults to `application/json`, but jackson is registered to serialize/deserialize anything matching `application/*+json`